# Juntar colunas diferentes no mesmo resultado

Tags: postgresql, select, join

Estou tentando gerar um SELECT em PostgreSQL que junte colunas de diferentes tabelas na mesma coluna do resultado. 

Exemplo:

```
Usuario
-----------------------
| id | nome  |  regra |
|---------------------|
|   1| João  |  ADM   |
|---------------------|
|   2| Paulo |  USER  |
-----------------------

Permissao
-----------------------------------
| id |     regra     | usuario_id |
|---------------------------------|
|  1 | saida_produto |          2 |
-----------------------------------

SELECT Usuario.id, Permissao.regra, Usuario.regra from Usuario 
LEFT JOIN Permissao 
ON Permissao.usuario_id = Usuario.id 
WHERE Usuario.id = 2;

Resultado
     id  | regra         |   regra    
---------+---------------+-----------
      2  | saida_produto |   USER

Resultado Pretendido
 id  |   regra       
-----+---------------
  2  | saida_produto
  2  | USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas versões para testar a de melhor desempenho. Primeira:

```
with u as (
    select id, regra
    from usuario
    where id = 2
)
select *
from (
    select id, regra
    from u

    union all

    select usuario_id, regra
    from permissao p
    where exists (
        select 1
        from u
        where id = p.usuario_id
    )
) s
```

Segunda:

```
select *
from (
    select id, regra
    from usuario

    union all

    select usuario_id, regra
    from permissao p
    where exists (
        select 1
        from usuario
        where id = p.usuario_id
    )
) s
where id = 2;
```